# Can I separate tags with comma in HTL Slightly?

Tags: properties, aem, meta-tags, sightly

My problem is: I have to customize properties of a meta tag on AEM Console.

I have this meta tag:

```
<meta name="tags" data-sly-test="${properties.tag}" content="${properties.tag}" />
```

If an utent add more attributes on AEM console, I need that these attributes are separeted by ';'.

The output should be:

```
<meta name="tags" content="hello;world;laptop;screen"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `join` option (https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#124-array-join):

```
content="${properties.tag @ join=';'}"
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work for me, I resolved with multitag. T